# Dynamically resize div to for expanding lists using css

Tags: html, css, list, dynamic, expandable

I have my css layout, a div container with an expandable list inside.  I want my div to expand with the list.  Now it just overlaps the footer or hides it.  Below is the css code for the div the list is in with the list being hidden when expanded.  Thanks for any help.

```
#div {
clear: both;
width: 880px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0 70px 0 40px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: Remove the height attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` to `min-height`. It would help.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for.  So simple and easy I just overlooked it.